# The definition of 'clause' in modern grammar: construction vs function

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses, reduced-relative-clauses

Most modern grammars recognize **verbless clauses** such as *the boy on the roof* in (1) and *on the roof* in (2):

> (1) With *the boy on the roof*, they feared he might jump off it.
>
> (2) When *on the roof*, he might jump off it.

In these modern grammars, thus, having a verb is not a necessary condition for being a clause.

Having a verb is not a sufficient condition for qualifying as a clause, either. In (3), for example, *frequently asked* is a verb phrase (VP) containing a verb 'asked' (in the form of a past participle) but is not considered a clause in the same modern grammars.

> (3) Each week, we answer *frequently asked* questions about life during the coronavirus crisis.

Therefore, I conclude that having a verb is neither a necessary nor a sufficient condition for being a clause in those modern grammars. With this in mind, let's look at this pair:

> (4) The boy *who was on the roof* jumped off it.
>
> (5) The boy *on the roof* jumped off it.

They mean the same thing but, in those modern grammars that recognize verbless clauses, *who was on the roof* in (4) qualifies as a clause (a relative clause) whereas *on the roof* in (5) does not.

Note that in (1) and (2) above, *the boy on the roof* and *on the roof* are classified as clauses not because of their internal construction but because of their external functionality. And also note that from (1) through (3), having a verb has no logical connection with being a clause. Then, why is it that *who was on the roof* is treated as a clause in (4) whereas *on the roof* is not in (5) when they seem to have the same function of modifying the noun *boy*?

---

By "modern grammars" I mean descriptive grammars compiling the past sixty years or so of linguistic research. "Modern grammars" are distinguishable from "traditional grammars", which are prescriptively established without the help of extensive linguistic research.

Examples of modern grammars include:

1. *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (by Randolph Quirk, Sidney Greenbaum, Geoffrey Leech, and Jan Svartvik)
2. *Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English* (by Douglas Biber, Stig Johansson, Geoffrey Leech)
3. *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (by Rodney Huddleston, Geoffrey K. Pullum)
4. *Oxford Modern English Grammar* (by Bas Aarts)

Comment: You write *Note that in (1) and (2) above, the boy on the roof and on the roof are classified as clauses not because of their internal construction but because of their external functionality.* I can see why you say this, but this is not quite correct. Note that in (1) *the boy* is a constituent of the clause whereas in (5) *the boy* is not a constituent at all. The two constituents in *the boy on the roof* in (5) are the Determiner *the* and the Head nominal *boy on the roof*. It's all about internal structure.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes, their internal structures are different. And I agree with your analysis of the different structures. But I believe the difference doesn't arise from within but from outside. In other words, you can't analyze the internal structure of _the boy on the roof_ until you know its function within a bigger structure. Note that in (1), (2), (4) and (5), _on the roof_ constitutes a constituent having the same internal structure but that it has different functions: a predicate in (1) and (2); not a predicate in (4) and (5); and a clause only in (2).

Comment: I have no idea which "modern grammars" you're referring to, nor what their creators would do with your data. In fact, what you're talking about appears to be what I would call "reduced relative clauses", and the (no doubt not "modern" enough) process I would attribute them to was called _Whiz_-Deletion back in the Paleozoic. There are any number of variations on standard themes that relate clauses with non-(officially)-clausal material without meaning changes. So you can call them "clauses" or you can refuse to do so, and nothing will change.

Comment: That's what I had said @John Lawler. Now that you corroborate this, I feel bad about removing my comment. :)

Comment: Past perfect comments are off-topic.

Comment: @JohnLawler How do you get a relative clause out of "*with the boy on the roof*" in (1)? The meaning there is very different from *the boy in the roof* in *The boy on the roof, he's my friend*, for example, where *the boy on the roof* is an NP.

Comment: @JohnLawler Granted, "modern grammars" is not a well-defined term, but I've added an explanation of the term above. Although some of the modern grammars cited above do mention "reduced relative clauses", none of them mentions "Whiz-Deletion". And none of those modern grammars that do mention "reduced relative clauses" would treat the prepositional phrase _on the roof_ in (5) as a reduced relative clause, primarily because prepositional phrases can't be explained as reduced relative clauses in a coherent fashion.

Comment: Not sure why reducing the relative clause *who was on the roof* by removing *who was* to create a reduced relative clause is incoherent as an explanation.

Comment: @TinfoilHat in example (5) there is a case for that but not in (1). Compare with *With the bomb diffused it was safe to leave* This does not mean “With the bomb which was diffused it was safe to leave”. Nobody left carrying a diffused bomb!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: I was comparing only the relative constructions in 4 and 5, in reference to the OP's comment that there is no coherent explanation. There are no relative constructions here: *With experts having diffused the bomb, it was safe to leave.* *With the bomb having been diffused [by experts], it was safe to leave.* (passive) *The bomb diffused, it was safe to leave.*

Comment: If you don't have McCawley 1998, you're not looking at the last 50 years of grammar at all. Obviously the fix is in.

Comment: @TinfoilHat First, traditional grammars resorting to "reduced relative clause", they don't treat the PP _on the roof_ in (5) as a "clause". If they did, they would treat any PP modifying a noun as a "verbless clause". But no traditional (or modern) grammar I know of does so. Second, modern grammars all treat PPs as in (5) as "postmodification by PP", not as "reduced relative clauses". This is because these PPs cannot be explained coherently as "reduced relative clauses". In _The right man for the job is John_, for example, how could you explain _for the job_ as a reduced relative clause?

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't have access to _The Syntactic Phenomena of English_ by McCawley (1998). If you think it has answers to my question, please write up an answer citing the book. That said, I doubt that McCawley (1998) has an answer that the other modern grammars don't have, given that the late McCawley himself was named as one of linguists who served as a Board of Consultants for CaGEL by H&P. But I'd be glad to be proved wrong.

Comment: In "traditional" grammars, not every PP need be understood as a reduced relative. So there would be no need to defend *for the job* as a reduced relative.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Neither traditional nor modern grammars dare argue that every PP needs to be understood as a reduced relative clause, precisely because not every PP can be. I really don't think whatever approach traditional grammars take is ever coherent. And that's precisely why modern grammars come in. So I'm not interested in understanding traditional grammars. I'm only interested in how modern grammars would treat this issue.

Comment: *I really don't think whatever approach traditional grammars take is ever coherent.* 1. "If you have two grammarians, you will have three theories." 2. All "Modern Grammars" become traditional - if successful." 3. Consider the terms used for the "-ing" form of the verb: at the edges, things become fuzzy. 4. You are asking for this forum to give a definitive description of a clause. And not only that, but one upon which everyone, including you, will agree.

Comment: @Greybeard So what's your point? That I'm asking about what you think is impossible to answer? Then, please don't bother and be on your way.